# Watching map entries in VS debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I'm wondering if this is a mistake/misunderstanding on my end (most likely) or something else.

I have following code in VS 2017 Community:

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> myMap{};
    myMap[1] = 4;
    myMap[4] = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Now when I debug and I want to try to watch certain entries of the map I get

```
    myMap[1]    no operator "[]" matches these operands
```

Why is this the case? I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you perhaps debugging an optimized build? Debugging optimized code can often be surprising since the generated code can be *quite* different from the original C++ and many things can be optimized away and switched around. Try a debug build.

Comment: It's in debug configuration

Comment: Can people downvoting or voting for close at least comment why?

Comment: Betting it's the same folk who didn't understand what you were asking. I understood. Looks like Jesper and Caleth understood. And it looks like Caleth types faster than I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger is treating `myMap` as `const`. This is to stop you changing the state to observe it.

The two overloads for `[]` are

```
T& operator[]( const Key& key );
T& operator[]( Key&& key );
```

Neither of which are callable on a `const map`, as they insert a default constructed entry to return if `key` is not present.

You can instead use `at`, which throws if `key` is not present, and so has a `const` qualified overload

```
const T& at( const Key& key ) const;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you've declared your map to have the name "map". Because the name "map" is already used by the map object type, you cannot use it in this way.

If you change your map name to something else, eg

```
std::map<int, int> myMap{}
```

And call it using that name rather than the word "map", you should see the behaviour you are expecting

Comment: That doesn't make a difference

Comment: And `std::map` is a different beast from `map`.